# registration email from php not recieving data 1715247@linweb.ahost.me

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been working on a registration email for last 30 mins and i've come up blank. When the user submits the form, I want to get the first, last and username from the form and email this to the users email. I know this can be done via the _POST method and basic mail function, but it doesn't appear to work correctly, everytime an email is sent i recieve it from 1715247@linweb.ahost.me containing no data.

```
<?php $this->load->view('user/includes/simple_header');?>
<style type="text/css">
    .alert { padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 0px; }
    .alert-danger { background-color: #D60808; border-color:#D60808; } .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus,
    .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {border-color:#999999; background-color:#999999 }
    .btn-primary { background-color:#d60808; border-color:#d60808; }
    .well { padding: 10px; border-radius: 0px; }
 </style>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
 $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
 $email = $_POST['email_address'];
}
 // send email
 $to = 'test@testing';
 $subject = 'Signup Email.';
 $msg =
 "This is an autogenerated message from PPL Support. Please do not reply to this.\n\n" .
 "First Name: $firstname\n" .
 "Last Name: $lastname\n" .
 "Email: $email\n" .
 "Best regards,\n";
 $headers = '$headers = 'From: test@test.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer:     PHP/' . phpversion();'
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="well col-md-5 center login-box">

<?php
  $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
    echo validation_errors();

  $attributes = array('class' => 'form-signin form-horizontal' , 'id' => 'altForm' , 'name' => 'Signup');
    echo form_open_multipart('user/signup', $attributes);
?>

<fieldset class="fieldset_class">
  <legend><span class="whitetext">Contact Details</span></legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">First Name</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
            $first_name = array(
              'name'        => 'first_name',
              'class'          => 'form-control validate[required] text-input',
              'placeholder'   => 'First name',
              'value'   => set_value('first_name')
            );
             echo form_input($first_name);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Last Name</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $last_name = array(
              'name'        => 'last_name',
              'class'          => 'form-control validate[required] text-input',
              'placeholder'   => 'Last name',
              'value'   => set_value('last_name')
            );
             echo form_input($last_name);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Email Address</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
      <span id="msgbox_email" style="display:none"></span>
        <?php
             $email_address = array(
              'name'        => 'email_address',
              'class'          => 'form-control validate[required,custom[email]] text-input',
              'placeholder'   => 'Email Address',
              'id' => 'email_id',
              'value'   => set_value('email_address')
            );
             echo form_input($email_address);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Upload Profile Image</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
            $user_image = array(
              'name'        => 'user_image',
              'class'          => 'form-control'
            );
             echo form_upload($user_image);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset_class">
    <legend><span class="whitetext">Your Club Details</span></legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">License Type?</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $license_type_option = array(
           'PPL(A)'  => 'PPL(A)',
           'CPL(A)'    => 'CPL(A)',
           'NPPL(A)'    => 'NPPL(A)',
           'ATPL(A)'    => 'ATPL(A)',
           'OTHER'    => 'OTHER');
         echo form_dropdown('license_type', $license_type_option, '', 'class="form-control validate[required]" id="standard-list1"');
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Local Flying Club</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $institute = array(
              'name'        => 'institute',
              'class'          => 'form-control',
              'placeholder'   => 'Local Flying Club',
              'value'   => set_value('institute')
            );
             echo form_input($institute);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Local Airfield</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $local_flying_club = array(
              'name'        => 'local_flying_club',
              'class'          => 'form-control',
              'placeholder'   => 'Local Airfield',
              'value'   => set_value('local_flying_club')
            );
             echo form_input($local_flying_club);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>
  <fieldset class="fieldset_class">
    <legend><span class="whitetext">Login Details</span></legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">User Name</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
      <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
        <?php
          $username = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'class'          => 'form-control validate[required] text-input',
              'placeholder'   => 'User Name',
              'id' => 'username',
              'value'   => set_value('username')
            );
             echo form_input($username);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Password</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $password = array(
              'name'        => 'password',
              'class'          => 'form-control validate[required] text-input',
              'id'          => 'password',
              'placeholder'   => 'Password'
            );
             echo form_password($password);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="whitetext">Confirm Password</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php
        $password2 = array(
              'name'        => 'password2',
              'class'          => 'form-control validate[required,equals[password]] text-input',
              'id'          => 'password2',
              'placeholder'   => 'Confirm Password',
            );
             echo form_password($password2);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Account', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<?php echo form_close();

$this->load->view('user/includes/simple_footer'); ?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: right off the bat and without having to see your whole code, tells me you don't have a `From:` - Do read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - *Right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Don't dump *any* code in comments @MichaelRodwell. Edit your original post with updates.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this site. I've updated the original post.

Comment: again, no form tags with anything related to POST to support the question. *Right again Sam?* - @JayBlanchard *Running away...*

Comment: Can you give me an example? @JayBlanchard

Comment: Give you an example of what @MichaelRodwell?

Comment: @JayBlanchard form tags to support the "POST" in php.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: codeigniter bootstrap @JayBlanchard